# edit excel sheet cell with python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to edit excel sheet cell by python.
for edit i am using following code:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

xl_file = r'D:\path\excel.xls'
rb = open_workbook(xl_file)
wb = copy(rb)
sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)
sheet.write(0,2,'New_Data_For_Cell')
wb.save(xl_file)
```

with this code cell value update successfully but the entire excel sheet background color format change to default.

i want to keep all colors and formatting with updated cell value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To keep the formatting of excel sheet
you should use

> formatting_info=True

with open_workbook

here is the working code:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

xl_file = r'D:\path\excel.xls'
rb = open_workbook(xl_file, formatting_info=True)
wb = copy(rb)
sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)
sheet.write(0,2,'New_Data_For_Cell')
wb.save(xl_file)
```

Comment: I get sheet has no attribute write.